# How to remove the index column after flattening MultiIndex columns and apply styling to the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-styles

I have a sample pandas dataframe with 3 columns.

Here's the sample dataset -

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:                     'mode': ['car'] * 4 + ['train'] * 3 + ['truck'] * 5,
   ...:                     'qty1': [2,4,9,7,6,3,4,1,2,5,5,7],
   ...:                     'qty2': [5,2,3,6,9,7,4,5,1,6,3,9]
   ...:                   })
   ...: df
Out[3]:
     mode  qty1  qty2
0     car     2     5
1     car     4     2
2     car     9     3
3     car     7     6
4   train     6     9
5   train     3     7
6   train     4     4
7   truck     1     5
8   truck     2     1
9   truck     5     6
10  truck     5     3
11  truck     7     9
```

Now I have used `pivot_table` to get the following output -

```
In [4]: pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(data=df,
   ...:                         index=['mode'],
   ...:                         values=['qty1','qty2'],
   ...:                         aggfunc='sum')

In [5]: pivot1
Out[5]:
       qty1  qty2
mode
car      22    16
train    13    20
truck    20    24
```

Now when I apply the following code,

```
In [7]: pivot1 = pivot1.style.set_table_styles([^M
   ...:                           {^M
   ...:                                 "selector":"th",^M
   ...:                                 "props": [("border", "1px solid black"),^M
   ...:                                           ("font-style", "italic")]^M
   ...:                             },^M
   ...:                             {^M
   ...:                                 "selector":"th.row_heading",^M
   ...:                                 "props": [("border", "1px solid black"),^M
   ...:                                           ("font-style", "italic")]^M
   ...:                             }                           ^M
   ...:                         ]).set_properties(border="1px solid black").format('${:.2f}')
   ...: pivot1
```

I get the following output -
[Styled Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42YHv.png)

Now I actually want all the **column headers** - 'mode', 'qty1' and 'qty2' on **one level**. I tried resetting the index using `reset_index()` but I don't want the index column after resetting the index. I want the final table to look like this -

| mode | qty1 | qty2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | $22.00 | $16.00 |
| train | $13.00 | $20.00 |
| truck | $20.00 | $24.00 |

My end goal is to save this table as png/jpg and upload it to a pptx presentation using python.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode` is the index name, you can assign the index name to column header name

```py
pivot1.columns.name, pivot1.index.name = pivot1.index.name, None
```

```
print(pivot1)

mode   qty1  qty2
car      22    16
train    13    20
truck    20    24
```